# The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context. Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, powerbi, sspi

I am getting the error the target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context when trying to access a database that is in an Azure SQL Database when using Power BI Desktop

Has anyone else encountered this?

Management studio **can** connect to the database (once logged into my Azure account)

I have ensured that I am signed into Power BI with an account that has access to the database

I have ensured that the client machine IP address is allowed access to the database via the firewall on the database server in Azure

The database server also allows access to Azure services

Paul

Comment: Are you still experiencing a problem with this?

Comment: Second question - did you happen to recently change SQL service from using a local system account over to a domain account?

Comment: Having same issue. Any Solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try to connect over TCP port and not by instance name.
Type into "Server" field: `{SQL-server-IP},{SQL-server-port}`, example `192.168.1.5,54222`.
It's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change the compatibility level of the database to 130. I have found some users experimenting a similar error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735814/ssdt-failing-to-publish-unable-to-connect-to-master-or-target-server/46736185).

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name   
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL =  130;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that "Named Pipes" are enabled from  "SQL Server Configuration Manager".

1. Open "SQL Server Configuration Manager".
2. Expand "SQL Server Network Configuration", from the list on the left.
3. Select "Protocols for [Your Instance Name]".
4. Right click on "Named Pipes", from the list on the right.
5. Select "Enable"
6. Restart your Instance service.