# SQL Server deploy database to Azure throws "You must have a user with the same password..."

Tags: azure, ssms

I have a live SQL Server database which was originally on an Express version and has compatibility 100. I am inspecting it using SSMS 2016 RC, which seems to have highest compatibility level of 120.

On performing the task `Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL Database...` it goes through all the verification steps and then bails out with the error:

> Could not import package. Unable to connect to master or target server X. You must have a user with the same password in master or target server X

Is the only solution to upgrade the compatibility version of the database and is that even possible from such an old level? Do I have to install a newer SSMS to do this?

I've seen a similar question below, but it refers to SSDT, not SSMS:
[SSDT failing to publish: "Unable to connect to master or target server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735814/ssdt-failing-to-publish-unable-to-connect-to-master-or-target-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed latest SSMS v18.3 and performed the deploy operation again and it went through without a hitch, without even requiring me to change the compatibility level