# SSDT: Unable to connect to master or target server 'DB_NAME'. You must have a user with the same password in master or target server 'DB_NAME'

Tags: azure-devops, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac, sql-server-2019, ssdt-2019

I am going to automate the database deployment through SSDT-DACPAC by using Visual Studio 2019, DATABASE from where changes will deploy is SQL SERVER 2019, and for deployment medium I am using Azure pipeline and task 'SQL Server database deploy' when deployment starts it throw an error

```
  *** Could not deploy package.
      Unable to connect to master or target server 'DB_NAME'. You must have a user with the same 
      password in master or target server 'DB_NAME'.
```

Although I have double verifies the database's user and the password, same password connects me to ssms

**Please find log**

```
2020-07-22T06:51:57.3001061Z ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Deploy using : dacpac'
2020-07-22T06:51:57.3004812Z ##[debug]Evaluating: succeeded()
2020-07-22T06:51:57.3005875Z ##[debug]Evaluating succeeded:
2020-07-22T06:51:57.3008135Z ##[debug]=> True
2020-07-22T06:51:57.3009350Z ##[debug]Result: True
2020-07-22T06:51:57.3010674Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy using : dacpac
2020-07-22T06:51:57.3715291Z ==============================================================================
2020-07-22T06:51:57.3716242Z Task         : SQL Server database deploy
2020-07-22T06:51:57.3717049Z Description  : Deploy a SQL Server database using DACPAC or SQL scripts
2020-07-22T06:51:57.3717746Z Version      : 0.3.23
2020-07-22T06:51:57.3718317Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-07-22T06:51:57.3719290Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-dacpac-deployment-on-machine-group
2020-07-22T06:51:57.3720387Z ==============================================================================
2020-07-22T06:51:59.4759713Z ##[debug]VstsTaskSdk 0.8.2 commit 
2020-07-22T06:51:59.7919661Z ##[debug]Entering C:\azagent\A1\_work\_tasks\SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup_4b506f7f-720f-47bb-bf21-029bac6a690d\0.3.23\Main.ps1.
2020-07-22T06:51:59.8208606Z ##[debug]Loading resource strings from: C:\azagent\A1\_work\_tasks\SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup_4b506f7f-720f-47bb-bf21-029bac6a690d\0.3.23\Task.json
2020-07-22T06:51:59.8849723Z ##[debug]Loaded 6 strings.
2020-07-22T06:51:59.8951721Z ##[debug]SYSTEM_CULTURE: 'en-US'
2020-07-22T06:51:59.9013310Z ##[debug]Loading resource strings from: C:\azagent\A1\_work\_tasks\SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup_4b506f7f-720f-47bb-bf21-029bac6a690d\0.3.23\Strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
2020-07-22T06:51:59.9474383Z ##[debug]Loaded 6 strings.
2020-07-22T06:52:00.0039076Z ##[debug]INPUT_TASKTYPE: 'dacpac'
2020-07-22T06:52:00.0080924Z ##[debug]INPUT_DACPACFILE: 'C:\azagent\A1\_work\r1\a\_ActionAPI-CI-QA\artifact-actiondacpac-QA\New_sql_2019\bin\Release\New_sql_2019.dacpac'
2020-07-22T06:52:00.0120089Z ##[debug]INPUT_SQLFILE (empty)
2020-07-22T06:52:00.0212373Z ##[debug]INPUT_EXECUTEINTRANSACTION: 'false'
2020-07-22T06:52:00.0264618Z ##[debug] Converted to bool: False
2020-07-22T06:52:00.0307892Z ##[debug]INPUT_EXCLUSIVELOCK: 'false'
2020-07-22T06:52:00.0340171Z ##[debug] Converted to bool: False
2020-07-22T06:52:00.0382331Z ##[debug]INPUT_APPLOCKNAME (empty)
2020-07-22T06:52:00.0424011Z ##[debug]INPUT_INLINESQL (empty)
2020-07-22T06:52:00.0464722Z ##[debug]INPUT_TARGETMETHOD: 'server'
2020-07-22T06:52:00.0505622Z ##[debug]INPUT_SERVERNAME: 'dbserver3\SQL2019'
2020-07-22T06:52:00.0545057Z ##[debug]INPUT_DATABASENAME: 'RIN.ActionDB_QA'
2020-07-22T06:52:00.0586508Z ##[debug]INPUT_AUTHSCHEME: 'sqlServerAuthentication'
2020-07-22T06:52:00.0632381Z ##[debug]INPUT_SQLUSERNAME: 'rin'
2020-07-22T06:52:00.0681228Z ##[debug]INPUT_SQLPASSWORD: 'password'
2020-07-22T06:52:00.0735301Z ##[debug]INPUT_CONNECTIONSTRING (empty)
2020-07-22T06:52:00.0772570Z ##[debug]INPUT_PUBLISHPROFILE (empty)
2020-07-22T06:52:00.0817000Z ##[debug]INPUT_ADDITIONALARGUMENTS (empty)
2020-07-22T06:52:00.0882965Z ##[debug]INPUT_ADDITIONALARGUMENTSSQL (empty)
2020-07-22T06:52:00.0931191Z ##[debug]Loading module from path 'C:\azagent\A1\_work\_tasks\SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup_4b506f7f-720f-47bb-bf21-029bac6a690d\0.3.23\ps_modules\TaskModuleSqlUtility\TaskModuleSqlUtility.psd1'.
2020-07-22T06:52:00.1050744Z ##[debug]Loading module from path 'C:\azagent\A1\_work\_tasks\SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup_4b506f7f-720f-47bb-bf21-029bac6a690d\0.3.23\ps_modules\TaskModuleSqlUtility\TaskModuleSqlUtility.psm1'.
2020-07-22T06:52:00.1326840Z ##[debug]NonInteractive: False
2020-07-22T06:52:00.1648048Z ##[debug]Exporting function 'Invoke-DacpacDeployment'.
2020-07-22T06:52:00.1675075Z ##[debug]Exporting function 'Invoke-SqlQueryDeployment'.
2020-07-22T06:52:00.1701383Z ##[debug]Adding exceptions types.
2020-07-22T06:52:00.3872234Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Invoke-DacpacDeployment'.
2020-07-22T06:52:00.3901455Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Invoke-SqlQueryDeployment'.
2020-07-22T06:52:00.4862535Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[telemetry.publish area=SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup;feature=SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup]{"serverName": "f63420c3593aba48d436b02f3f6972d442f242a4e4219d64244779988f9d0d65","databaseName": "c50699da6b72abf28b7d2c4f0fda79467ec5e64667447691e616c357eae8be88"}
2020-07-22T06:52:00.8502242Z ##[debug]Finding files with pattern C:\azagent\A1\_work\r1\a\_ActionAPI-CI-QA\artifact-actiondacpac-QA\New_sql_2019\bin\Release\New_sql_2019.dacpac
2020-07-22T06:52:00.8790446Z ##[debug]Entering Find-VstsFiles.
2020-07-22T06:52:00.9038975Z ##[debug] LegacyPattern: 'C:\azagent\A1\_work\r1\a\_ActionAPI-CI-QA\artifact-actiondacpac-QA\New_sql_2019\bin\Release\New_sql_2019.dacpac'
2020-07-22T06:52:01.0124279Z ##[debug]Entering Get-MatchingItems.
2020-07-22T06:52:01.0215255Z ##[debug] IncludePatterns: 'C:\azagent\A1\_work\r1\a\_ActionAPI-CI-QA\artifact-actiondacpac-QA\New_sql_2019\bin\Release\New_sql_2019.dacpac'
2020-07-22T06:52:01.0319618Z ##[debug] ExcludePatterns: ''
2020-07-22T06:52:01.0408540Z ##[debug] IncludeFiles: 'True'
2020-07-22T06:52:01.0446810Z ##[debug] IncludeDirectories: 'False'
2020-07-22T06:52:01.0484071Z ##[debug] Force: 'False'
2020-07-22T06:52:01.3472741Z ##[debug]Path: C:\azagent\A1\_work\r1\a\_ActionAPI-CI-QA\artifact-actiondacpac-QA\New_sql_2019\bin\Release\New_sql_2019.dacpac
2020-07-22T06:52:01.3551260Z ##[debug]Leaving Get-MatchingItems.
2020-07-22T06:52:01.3583140Z ##[debug]Total found: 1
2020-07-22T06:52:01.3618825Z ##[debug]Leaving Find-VstsFiles.
2020-07-22T06:52:01.3659339Z ##[debug]Matched files = C:\azagent\A1\_work\r1\a\_ActionAPI-CI-QA\artifact-actiondacpac-QA\New_sql_2019\bin\Release\New_sql_2019.dacpac
2020-07-22T06:52:01.3742957Z ##[debug]Entering script SqlPackageOnTargetMachines.ps1
2020-07-22T06:52:01.4711292Z ##[debug]Sql Versions installed on machine DBSERVER3 as read from registry: 150 140 130 120 110 100 90
2020-07-22T06:52:01.5560135Z ##[debug]Sql Version Specific Root Dir for version 150 as read from registry: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\
2020-07-22T06:52:01.5665581Z ##[debug]Sql Version Specific Root Dir for version 150 as read from registry: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\
2020-07-22T06:52:01.5752688Z ##[debug]Sql Version Specific Root Dir for version 140 as read from registry: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\
2020-07-22T06:52:01.5805157Z ##[debug]Sql Version Specific Root Dir for version 130 as read from registry: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\
2020-07-22T06:52:01.5860216Z ##[debug]Sql Version Specific Root Dir for version 130 as read from registry: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\
2020-07-22T06:52:01.5912627Z ##[debug]Dac Framework installed with SQL Version 130 found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Dac\bin\SqlPackage.exe on machine DBSERVER3
2020-07-22T06:52:01.7103800Z ##[debug]Dac Framework installed with SQL Version 130 found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe on machine DBSERVER3
2020-07-22T06:52:01.7487680Z ##[debug]Visual Studio versions found on machine DBSERVER3 as read from registry: 14.0 12.0 11.0 10.0 8.0
2020-07-22T06:52:01.8538116Z ##[debug]Visual Studio install location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\
2020-07-22T06:52:01.8862724Z ##[debug]Dac Framework installed with Visual Studio found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\140\SqlPackage.exe on machine DBSERVER3
2020-07-22T06:52:01.9186060Z ##[debug]File is C:\azagent\A1\_work\r1\a\_ActionAPI-CI-QA\artifact-actiondacpac-QA\New_sql_2019\bin\Release\New_sql_2019.dacpac
2020-07-22T06:52:01.9520886Z ##[debug]Sqlpackage.exe arguments :  /SourceFile:"C:\azagent\A1\_work\r1\a\_ActionAPI-CI-QA\artifact-actiondacpac-QA\New_sql_2019\bin\Release\New_sql_2019.dacpac" /Action:Publish /TargetServerName:"dbserver3\SQL2019" /TargetDatabaseName:"RIN.ActionDB_QA" /TargetUser:"rin" /TargetPassword:"password" 
2020-07-22T06:52:01.9551359Z ##[debug] /SourceFile:"C:\azagent\A1\_work\r1\a\_ActionAPI-CI-QA\artifact-actiondacpac-QA\New_sql_2019\bin\Release\New_sql_2019.dacpac" /Action:Publish /TargetServerName:"dbserver3\SQL2019" /TargetDatabaseName:"RIN.ActionDB_QA" /TargetUser:"rin" /TargetPassword:"password" 
2020-07-22T06:52:01.9581010Z ##[debug]Executing command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\140\SqlPackage.exe  /SourceFile:"C:\azagent\A1\_work\r1\a\_ActionAPI-CI-QA\artifact-actiondacpac-QA\New_sql_2019\bin\Release\New_sql_2019.dacpac" /Action:Publish /TargetServerName:"dbserver3\SQL2019" /TargetDatabaseName:"RIN.ActionDB_QA" /TargetUser:"rin" /TargetPassword:"password" 
2020-07-22T06:52:04.3004630Z *** Could not deploy package.
2020-07-22T06:52:04.3005647Z Unable to connect to master or target server 'RIN.ActionDB_QA'. You must have a user with the same password in master or target server 'RIN.ActionDB_QA'.
2020-07-22T06:52:04.3382043Z ##[debug]Deployment failed with error : Publishing to database 'RIN.ActionDB_QA' on server 'dbserver3\SQL2019'. 
2020-07-22T06:52:04.3409470Z ##[debug]Initializing deployment (Start) 
2020-07-22T06:52:04.3435795Z ##[debug]Initializing deployment (Failed) 
2020-07-22T06:52:04.3458533Z ##[debug]
2020-07-22T06:52:04.3706793Z ##[debug]Write-Exception error:
2020-07-22T06:52:04.3786790Z ##[debug]Publishing to database 'RIN.ActionDB_QA' on server 'dbserver3\SQL2019'. 
2020-07-22T06:52:04.3813415Z ##[debug]Initializing deployment (Start) 
2020-07-22T06:52:04.3833536Z ##[debug]Initializing deployment (Failed) 
2020-07-22T06:52:04.3852670Z ##[debug]
2020-07-22T06:52:04.3908319Z ##[debug]Caught exception from task script.
2020-07-22T06:52:04.3958204Z ##[debug]Error record:
2020-07-22T06:52:04.5313400Z ##[debug]Publishing to database 'RIN.ActionDB_QA' on server 'dbserver3\SQL2019'. 
2020-07-22T06:52:04.5347974Z ##[debug]Initializing deployment (Start) 
2020-07-22T06:52:04.5381991Z ##[debug]Initializing deployment (Failed) 
2020-07-22T06:52:04.5419891Z ##[debug]
2020-07-22T06:52:04.5452059Z ##[debug]At C:\azagent\A1\_work\_tasks\SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup_4b506f7f-720f-47bb-bf21-029bac6a690d\0.3.23\ps_modules\TaskModuleSqlUtility\SqlPackageOnTargetMachines.ps1:567 char:10
2020-07-22T06:52:04.5478252Z ##[debug]+          throw  $result
2020-07-22T06:52:04.5504801Z ##[debug]+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-07-22T06:52:04.5533945Z ##[debug]    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Publishing to d...ent (Failed    ) 
2020-07-22T06:52:04.5561618Z ##[debug]:String) [], RuntimeException
2020-07-22T06:52:04.5591810Z ##[debug]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Publishing to database 'RIN.ActionDB_QA' on serv    er 'dbserver3\SQL2019'. 
2020-07-22T06:52:04.5620739Z ##[debug]Initializing deployment (Start) 
2020-07-22T06:52:04.5649754Z ##[debug]Initializing deployment (Failed) 
2020-07-22T06:52:04.5678829Z ##[debug]
2020-07-22T06:52:04.5709899Z ##[debug] 
2020-07-22T06:52:04.5759021Z ##[debug]Script stack trace:
2020-07-22T06:52:04.5857807Z ##[debug]at ExecuteCommand, C:\azagent\A1\_work\_tasks\SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup_4b506f7f-720f-47bb-bf21-029bac6a690d\0.3.23\ps_modules\TaskModuleSqlUtility\SqlPackageOnTargetMachines.ps1: line 567
2020-07-22T06:52:04.5888012Z ##[debug]at Invoke-DacpacDeployment, C:\azagent\A1\_work\_tasks\SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup_4b506f7f-720f-47bb-bf21-029bac6a690d\0.3.23\ps_modules\TaskModuleSqlUtility\SqlPackageOnTargetMachines.ps1: line 534
2020-07-22T06:52:04.5916543Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, C:\azagent\A1\_work\_tasks\SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup_4b506f7f-720f-47bb-bf21-029bac6a690d\0.3.23\Main.ps1: line 124
2020-07-22T06:52:04.5944487Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
2020-07-22T06:52:04.5974238Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 22
2020-07-22T06:52:04.6012463Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 18
2020-07-22T06:52:04.6042594Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
2020-07-22T06:52:04.6092535Z ##[debug]Exception:
2020-07-22T06:52:04.6195130Z ##[debug]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Publishing to database 'RIN.ActionDB_QA' on server 'dbserver3\SQL2019'. 
2020-07-22T06:52:04.6216331Z ##[debug]Initializing deployment (Start) 
2020-07-22T06:52:04.6238196Z ##[debug]Initializing deployment (Failed) 
2020-07-22T06:52:04.6259708Z ##[debug]
2020-07-22T06:52:04.6809953Z ##[error]Publishing to database 'RIN.ActionDB_QA' on server 'dbserver3\SQL2019'. 
Initializing deployment (Start) 
Initializing deployment (Failed) 

2020-07-22T06:52:04.6830979Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]Publishing to database 'RIN.ActionDB_QA' on server 'dbserver3\SQL2019'. %0D%0AInitializing deployment (Start) %0D%0AInitializing deployment (Failed) %0D%0A
2020-07-22T06:52:04.6834571Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed]
2020-07-22T06:52:04.7507980Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy using : dacpac
```

Comment: Check [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60956154/sql-server-deploy-database-to-azure-throws-you-must-have-a-user-with-the-same-p). I tested with the SSMS V18.2 and it could be deployed succssfully.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the log. I analyzed the log and found the possible reason, you can check the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the deploy log, I notice that you are using the Deployment Group to run the `Sql database deploy task`.

The `Sql database deploy task` calls sqlpackage.exe on your local machine.

In the log, I also notice that the task is using the `sqlpackage.exe` from the `Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0` folder. It seems that this folder is for **visual studio 2015** instead of visual studio 2019.

On local machine the `sqlpackage.exe` exists in the path:`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\150`

Here are the sample script, you could refer to it:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\150

SqlPackage.exe  /SourceFile:"C:\xxx\FIle\filename.dacpac" /Action:Publish /TargetServerName:"KEVINL\SQLEXPRESS" /TargetDatabaseName:"Testkevin6" /TargetUser:"MyNewAdminUser" /TargetPassword:"xxx"
```

[image]

You could try to use the sqlpackage.exe from visual studio 2019. If it could work, you could try to change the agent environemnt value.

Comment: I think you save my life, basically sql 2019 is not on my local machine its on separate server and database team is responsible for managing that server, so I will contact them and ask for the VS version and sure short VS 2015 may install, if this true than i ill ask them to install VS 2019 as well

Comment: Yes the SSDT 2019  was not installed on the server, after installation deployment for db changes smoothly deployed.
Once again thanks....!